# Append data in newly created Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I had written a Macro which pastes data from Sheet1 to a new Worksheet.
Now I want to select some data from Sheet1 and append it below the data in the new worksheet. Problem is while pasting the data 1st time, I did not assign a name to the new worksheet. Hence, don't know how to where to make the edits in code. Can anyone please help?

```
Sub PasteNewWS()
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Comment: As long as you know where the new worksheet is (second sheet? last sheet?), you can use the Worksheets VBA object to address it. For instance `Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Range("A1")` refers to the first cell on the last worksheet in your workbook.

Answer (score 0):

`Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy` equals your top 4 lines.

New added sheet will be `ActiveSheet`, you can assign it to a varible.
`A1` is then `ActiveCell` on a new sheet by default.

```vb
Sub PasteNewWS()
    Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
    Dim newSht As Worksheet
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Set newSht = ActiveSheet
'    newSht.Range("A1").Select
    newSht.Paste
    newSht.Name = "Output" ' update as neede
End Sub
```

---

A condensed version

```
Sub PasteNewWS()
    Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=ActiveSheet).Name = "Output"
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Comment: `Set newSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=ActiveSheet)`.  Removes a line from your code.

Comment: I have updated with the more condensed code.